# android 9 get content from clipboard programmatically

Tags: android, clipboard, getcontent

I have a [project](https://github.com/pzoli/ClipboardShare/) for share clipboard content between phone and desktop service.

When I try getText from clipboard it return empty string. It worked previously for a few months on a Android Pie.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String clipContent = "";
MainActivity activity = ((MainActivity) getActivity());
if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
  ClipData clipData = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
  ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
  clipContent = item.getText().toString();
}
```

See [MainActivity.onActivityResult()](https://github.com/pzoli/ClipboardShare/blob/mai/clipboard-share/src/main/java/hu/infokristaly/clipboard/MainActivity.java).
Please help find solution.

Answer (score 0):

It will be enough to give the value you want to copy.

```
  ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("nonsense_data",
                            mResultEt.getText().toString());
                    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.copied_to_clipboard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Clipboard content was not text type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).